# What is this 15-foot weapon with "extended reach" I'm remembering?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, weapons, reach, content-identification

I'm drawing a blank, so I'm hoping someone will know what I'm talking about.  I remember seeing a weapon described as an "extended reach" weapon.  (That meant that it could attack only creatures 15 feet away from it.)

What I seem to remember:

- “Extended reach” property
- It was a humongous spear with a 10-foot shaft and a 5-foot spearhead
- It's based on a real weapon used in ancient Greece for siege warfare

I'm trying to find this weapon again because we have a Summoner in our party who has a huge eidolon. Normal and reach weapons don't work for this character while riding his pet. Having a weapon with a 15-foot reach would be great, you know?

What weapon am I thinking of?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [Sarissa](http://archivesofnethys.com/EquipmentWeaponsDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Sarissa) from the Giant Hunter's Handbook matches your description:

> This spearlike weapon is about 15 feet long. Its unwieldy length is counterbalanced by a heavy brass base. A sarissa provides **extended reach**—tripling your reach rather than doubling it. A Medium wielder would threaten spaces 10 to 15 feet away, but not adjacent squares or squares 5 to 10 feet away (as with a typical reach weapon).

Emphasis mine to show your use of 'extended reach' in the description.

Comment: YES!  That's absolutely the weapon I was asking about.  Thank you so much!

Comment: @Ev- To give you an idea how they might fight: the Macedon Phalanx had 4-5 meter (12-15 feet) spears. A medieval pike (longt&thin variant) is of similar length.